# Spark: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jackson

I am trying to do a simple Spark parallelize on some data within a big project but even on the simplest example I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/AsArraySerializerBase;
```

The error comes up with any simple parallelize, even this simple one. I don't have any idea where this error even came from

```
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("IEEG Spark").setMaster("local")
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val distVals = sc.parallelize(data)
    distVals.foreach(println)
```

and the following is my maven pom.xml file

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <groupId>astiefel</groupId>
    <artifactId>ieeg-spark</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Spark IEEG</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>edu.upenn.cis.ieeg</groupId>
        <artifactId>ieeg</artifactId>
        <version>1.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.upenn.cis.ieeg</groupId>
            <artifactId>ieeg-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>breeze_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

I'm so lost with this error, any tips as to where to even begin?

Answer (score 0):

You could do some simple Spark parallelize test with below dependency, it use 
spark-assembly-xxx.jar directly as a jar dependency.

```
<profile>
        <id>apache-spark/scala</id>
        <dependencies>
            <!--Apache Spark -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-assembly</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${spark.home}/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

Comment: But I think the problem is that I have other dependencies that use the jackson library but even when I change the version of it, I still get an error

Comment: maybe,  I have see bunch of questions about pom dependency issue, actually assembly jar is good for startup since it is stable release and contains everything

Comment: My solution is to override the other versions by placing a dependency to the newer jackson module in my own pom. Seems to have done the trick